# Remotely copying files from WebDAV server?

Tags: linux, webdav, copy

My iDisk is about to expire, and I can access it through the WebDAV protocol. I own my own server, and I know it's possible to access my iDisk through WebDAV.

I was wondering how I would go about initiating a transfer from a WebDAV-based server to a Linux machine through SSH access?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WebDAV is over HTTP and [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) is a great tool for recursively downloading a site, I suggesting using `wget -r http://your.iDisk.URL/`.

You may have to get a bit fancy and pass authentication options or even copy a cookie from your browser in order to maintain the session, but this tool should allow you to pull everything down over the console via ssh.

Alternately, consider [mount.davfs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.davfs) to treat the DAV site as a local filesystem and perform a regular recursive copy. This requires root and possibly a bit more work, but it is another option.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.

Comment: Looks like I can't authenticate to my iDisk because they're doing some fancy sort of authentication. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I use this method when on Mac OS X, as far as I know it should work fine.

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040920100413622

Comment: I'm unable to authenticate to my iDisk using this method because iDisk doesn't support SSH.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.